# When an entire row is selected, why does Selection.EntireColumn.Address return a row reference?

Tags: vba, excel, rows

If I manually select an arbitrary row, say `4:4`, and then in the Immediate pane use:

```
?Selection.EntireColumn.Address
$1:$1048576
```

That's not the column reference I was expecting.

But if manually select an arbitrary column, say `D:D`, and then in the Immediate pane use:

```
?Selection.EntireRow.Address
$1:$1048576
```

I *do* get the the expected row reference.

Are rows more dominant? Is there the *War of the Rows'*

Comment: ok, in the first one you're selecting a ROW and then changing it to ALL the columns in the ROW. This would then evaluate to all the rows in the workbook, which is the range you have. In the second one, you are selecting a COLUMN and then changing it to ALL the rows in the COLUMN. This would then evaluate to all the rows in the workbook, which is the range you have, and the same as above :)

Comment: `Selection.EntireColumn.Address & "/" & Selection.EntireRow.Address` gives `$1:$1048576/$4:$4` when `4:4` is selected, but gives `$D:$D/$1:$1048576` when `D:D` is selected, so it does appear that the selection of all the columns in the worksheet shows just the row notation.

Comment: ah, read it a bit too quick I think. Well, I would say, if you select the same range in 2 different ways, there would need to be a consistent output for the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the documentation for [Range.EntireColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834476.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a Range object that represents the entire column ***(or columns)***
>   that ***contains the specified range***.

When you select an entire row, the only Range that contains the intersection of every row and every column is the entire Worksheet.

The same thing obviously applies to `EntireRow` - when you select an entire column, the intersection of every column and every row is the entire Worksheet.

At that point it doesn't really matter how Excel presents the address (and in fact `ActiveSheet.Cells.Address` also outputs `$1:$1048576`, as does `Range("$A:$XFD").Address`).  The only thing that really matters is that they are reversible - that is that you could take the output of `.Address` and get the same thing back by passing it to `Range()`.

What it boils down to is that `Range("$1:$1048576").Address = Range("$A:$XFD").Address`.  All Excel has to work with is the `Range` itself when it builds the address to feed back to you.  So in this unique instance where it has 2 to choose from, it simply picks one.  Row notation makes as much sense as Column notation, and comes first in `.Cell(r, c)` addressing, so why not? On a preference note, I'm actually glad they make this call - I never remember that `XFD` is the maximum column address...

Remember also that the `Range` object has no information about where it came from, so it doesn't ***know*** that it was created with a call to `EntireRow` as opposed to `EntireColumn`. The *user's* expectation may be different, but then again the user has more context than the `Range`.